# Convert codeSnippet to Resharper Templates .Is there a utility for this?I

Tags: resharper

I love resharper it's fantastic. I wanted to post this in the resharper forum but for some reasons when creating an account it fails.Anyway back to my questions.

I have many codesnippets and I would like resharper to see them.Still today you are stuck apparently if you using resharper settings you cannot view them.

As anybody by anychance created an utility to convert them to resharper templates?

I dont know how to create live templates and even if I did i would have to create 100s of codesnippets manually which I am not going to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such utility that I'm aware of although it shouldn't be too complicated to create one. I have created a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273779) in ReSharper issue tracker to allow direct import of any VS snippets to live templates. Hoping it can be implemented one day.

It should be noted however that merely importing VS snippets to ReSharper templates is only a half of the story: VS snippets provide quite a poor choice of variables in templates whereas ReSharper exposes a rich set of [macros](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Choose_Macro.html) which allow deploying templates in a more intelligent manner.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have seen many posts regarding codesnippets but for some reasons reshaper team ignored it.I dont think it would be to difficult to implement an utility to import them.Even though resharper ones are more powerful,I sometimes worked in places where they dont allow to install software or dont want you to use resharper,so when creating a code snippet I always create in VS .Again very shortsighted not to offer such a utility.

Comment: Places where you're not supposed to use ReSharper? Really? What a shame